# Cannot find symbol - integer

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm learning Java and searched this error, which is very common.  But I cannot find the solution.  I'm trying to re-use the result of `finalScore`, but no matter how I declare it or where I place it, IntelliJ does not recognize it.  I know I'm missing something fundamentally obvious here.  How can I declare the integers so that they can be re-used in different methods?  Anywhere outside of the `gameOver` method is a problem.  I also tried `public static int finalScore` but that also threw error.  And `calculateScore.finalScore` but still error.

```
package com.test;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here



        calculateScore(true, 5, 5, 200, "sam");
        calculateScore(true, 5, 8, 200, "bob");
    }


    public static void displayHighScore(){


        if (finalScore > 100);           //problem line of code
        System.out.println("helloworld");
    }

    public static int calculateScore(boolean gameOver, int score, int levelCompleted, int bonus, String name) {

        if (gameOver) {
            int finalScore = score + (levelCompleted * bonus);
            finalScore += 2000;
            System.out.println("your final score was " + finalScore);
            return finalScore;

            if ((finalScore > 100) || (finalScore < 200));
            System.out.println( name "is in position 4");

        }
        return -1;    //if the above isn't required/doesn't run, this statement is:  else return -1
        //or we can just type is as } else { return -1;


        }
    }
```

Comment: It is very tough to read this code. Will you please edit it to a compiled version.

Comment: finalScore is not a global variable so how are you accessing it in the displayHighScore() function? Secondly you aren't storing the result obtained from calculateScore in a variable. Thirdly, the "return finalScore" line will always return the function so what is the purpose of the if statement inserted afterwards when it's not even going to run?

Comment: You should return the finalScore from calculateScore() function, store it in a variable and then pass that variable to the displayHigh Score function.

Comment: Thanks Kula, very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of problems in your code here. But for what you mentioned as the issue, you need to declare finalScore as global `static` variable as below

```
...
    static int finalScore;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here



        calculateScore(true, 5, 5, 200, "sam");
        calculateScore(true, 5, 8, 200, "bob");
    }
...
```

Also, you need to put the `return finalScore` statement at the end of the `if(gameOver)` block as below or you will get not reachable error for line `if ((finalScore > 100) || (finalScore < 200));`

```
if (gameOver) {
            finalScore = score + (levelCompleted * bonus);
            finalScore += 2000;
            System.out.println("your final score was " + finalScore);


            if ((finalScore > 100) || (finalScore < 200));
                System.out.println( name +"is in position 4");
            return finalScore;

        }
```

Comment: Makes sense thanks a lot!  I know the code has some issues but I can resolve most of it.  The main issue I keep encountering is this symbol not found and I was just trying to figure out how you declare it - e.g. static int finalScore.  So thank you.

Comment: @MatthewWalker Glad this helped. Please don't forget to upvote the post and accept as the answer if it really solves your issue. Cheers. Enjoy learning Java! :)

Comment: I up voted but no reputation to add +1 yet.  Marked as answered cheers.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :)